# What's keeping my screensaver from activating?

Tags: linux-mint, screensaver

I'm running Linux Mint 13 KDE on an HP Pavilion g6 laptop.

The screensaver, which in my case is `xscreensaver`, but I've noticed this behavior with `kscreensaver` as well, never seems to activate.

After observing it, I thought it was the touch pad being too sensitive, but disabling it didn't help.

Observing it, it seems to be detecting some kind of input from somewhere, as I've seen the screen dim after some time, then brighten back up without being touched at all, and when locked, I've seen the password box pop up on its own.

Is there any idea what's going on, or something I've overlooked?

Comment: try running `xev` - if you there are any events without you touching the input devices they should appear in its output.

Comment: Are you using vlc? https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/440321/3285

Answer (score 0):

First run `xdg-screensaver activate`. If that works, perhaps

- you're having problems with input being sent to the terminal
- perhaps something [like VLC](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/440321/3285) is inhibiting the screensaver.