# When using VLC, why does my screen saver keep waking up?

Tags: vlc, screensaver, xscreensaver, dpms

XScreenSaver uses DPMS to turn my laptop screen off. I'd like to find out why it's waking up to the prompt again. I enabled logging with `log`, but it shows nothing useful,

> xscreensaver: 22:04:21: logging to "/tmp/f" at Thu Apr 26 22:04:21 2018

That's all that's in the log. Checking `/var/log/kern.log`, I see

> xscreensaver: pam_ecryptfs: seteuid error

How can I debug this issue, what are the likely causes of XScreenSaver waking my display up. I'm using xscreensaver 5.36.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue. 
killing xscreensaver, and running

```
xscreensaver -verbose
```

gave me a bunch of:

```
xscreensaver: 01:23:58: ClientMessage DEACTIVATE received while inactive: resetting idle timer.
xscreensaver: 01:24:28: ClientMessage DEACTIVATE received while inactive: resetting idle timer.
xscreensaver: 01:24:58: ClientMessage DEACTIVATE received while inactive: resetting idle timer.
xscreensaver: 01:25:28: ClientMessage DEACTIVATE received while inactive: resetting idle timer.
xscreensaver: 01:25:58: ClientMessage DEACTIVATE received while inactive: resetting idle timer.
xscreensaver: 01:26:28: ClientMessage DEACTIVATE received while inactive: resetting idle timer.
xscreensaver: 01:26:58: ClientMessage DEACTIVATE received while inactive: resetting idle timer.
xscreensaver: 01:27:28: ClientMessage DEACTIVATE received while inactive: resetting idle timer.
xscreensaver: 01:27:58: ClientMessage DEACTIVATE received while inactive: resetting idle timer.
xscreensaver: 01:28:28: ClientMessage DEACTIVATE received while inactive: resetting idle timer.
xscreensaver: 01:28:58: ClientMessage DEACTIVATE received while inactive: resetting idle timer.
xscreensaver: 01:29:28: ClientMessage DEACTIVATE received while inactive: resetting idle timer.
xscreensaver: 01:29:58: ClientMessage DEACTIVATE received while inactive: resetting idle timer.
xscreensaver: 01:30:28: ClientMessage DEACTIVATE received while inactive: resetting idle timer.
xscreensaver: 01:30:58: ClientMessage DEACTIVATE received while inactive: resetting idle timer.
xscreensaver: 01:31:28: ClientMessage DEACTIVATE received while inactive: resetting idle timer.
```

I then started looking for stuff to kill. one thing was xfce4-power-manager, but that didn't do the trick.

There was no vlc window open, but I found a task running with

```
$ ps aux | grep vlc
poleguy   5568  0.1  0.0 1983844 12476 ?       Sl   Jan04  27:43 /usr/bin/vlc --started-from-file
```

it wouldn't kill normally so I did a

```
kill -kill 5568
```

and the DEACTIVATE messages went away! Not easy to track down, so I hope this helps someone trying to track down similar issues.

My monitors will sleep tonight!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in the [XScreenSaver FAQ](https://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/faq.html#no-blank).

> If you are using VLC, select *"Disable Screensaver"* somewhere in the VLC Preferences. (It tends to move around.) It's possible that this will disable the screen saver any time VLC is running, and **not only when it is playing.** I'm not sure.

For me it was under "Video" preferences. Alternatively in the file `~/.config/vlc/vlcrc` you'll see a line

```
# Disable screensaver (boolean)
#disable-screensaver=1
```

Un-comment that and set it to `0`, `disable-screensaver=0`, or you can simply run,

```
echo "disable-screensaver=0" >> ~/.config/vlc/vlcrc
```

[**If having completed the above does not solve your problem, perhaps you're using XFCE and running into problems with `xfce4-power-manager`?**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/325053/3285)